# regex with optional data at the front

Tags: regex

I have a regex that looks like this

```
((1010xxx)?(\d{11}|\d{10}|\d{7})+)
```

Basically I want it to match

8085551234
5551234
10102338085551234

and it should fail on
1010233

This is more for validation being done on an xsd than an actual matcher.

PS.
I am trying to match US telephone numbers 7 - 11 digits long with an optional 1010xxx at the front. Also if it is 1010xxx it should not pass. xxx is any 3 digits.

Comment: So you’re just having problems with the `xxx`?

Comment: Well, `1010233` matches `\d{7}`.

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to accomplish, not just test cases.  With the info you have provided, I would say that this is the answer: `(8085551234)|(5551234)|(10102338085551234)`

Comment: @Bart.  You are right, is there any way to say that if it is 7 digits it can not start with 10

Comment: I am trying to match US telephone numbers 7 - 11 digits long with an optional 1010xxx at the front.  Also if it is 1010xxx it should not pass.  xxx is any 3 digits.

Comment: @arinte, yes, you can do that. Look at Adam's answer. Only he defined the seven digit number not to start with `1010` instead of the `10` you now mention. I assume you can adjust that yourself ;)

Comment: Note that you probably don't need the `+` at the end. Leaving it there, will cause your regex to match *digit-strings* whose lengths are multiples of 7, 10 or 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to make sure that it's a 7, 10, or 11 digit string, making sure that if it's only 7 digits it doesn't start with '1010', you can use a negative lookahead assertion before your match on `\d{7}`, i.e.:

```
((\d{11}|\d{10}|(?!1010)\d{7})+)
```

Comment: Yes, but for some reason 10102334 passes?

Comment: It *contains* a 7-digit string.  If you don't want that to match either, you can put start and end anchors at the ends of the regex, e.g. ^((\d{11}|\d{10}|(?!1010)\d{7})+)$

Comment: Instead of \d{7}, if you are using the negative look behind, you should use `(?<!1010)\d{3}`

Comment: @Peter, why? What's wrong with the look ahead? Look ahead is over-all better supported by various regex flavors, so I don't see why you'd want to use look behind here.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused for a moment.  You're solution seems correct.

Comment: Peter, if the answer is correct, please mark it as such. And perhaps also "upvote" it.